# Web application doesn't start when JAR placed within lib folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar

I encountered a weird problem - when I put my application JAR within the WEB-INF/lib directory, it doesn't work. But when create a WEB-INF/classes directory and unzip my JAR there it works just fine .

Any help?

Comment: Define `doesn't work` please.  Do you have an exception stack trace you can show us?  Unfortunately my mind reading device is in the shop today.

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is wanted and completely natural.

- `/WEB-INF/classes` has to contain the classes of your Java EE application. If you had used an IDE to pack a WAR (Web application ARchive) file, you would have noticed your application getting placed exactly there. A WAR file is the usual way for deploying.
- As the name says `/WEB-INF/lib` is the default search path for *libraries*. Libraries are usually distributed as JAR file and therefore these are placed in the `lib` directory.

In conclusion, it's now obvious why it won't work if you place your application JAR in the `lib` directory because of two mistakes - your files shouldn't be packed in any archive and the `lib` directory is for (packed) libraries.

Comment: i have created a jar containing all my JEE application classes , and was intending to use the generated jar as a packed library , isn't this possible ?

Comment: This is definitely possible, you just have to get the gist of the application / library thing. If you're developing a library, it's fine, pack a jar and place it in libraries folder. But don't wonder if you launch your webserver and it refuses to launch because there's no application actually *doing* anything or providing servlets. To test your application, create something that actually makes use of your libary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dragging and dropping the JAR file into the WEB-INF/lib directory? Make sure to just have it copy, not extract the whole JAR into the folder.